# Populate spinner with years dynamically in Android?

Tags: android, dynamic, insert, spinner

I have been racking my brain trying to get this to work. I want to dynamically enter in years from 1900 to the current year into a spinner. I don't think that this is possible to do using an XML defined array but can I do it with an array adapter? Here is what I have so far:

```
ArrayList<String> years = new ArrayList<String>();
int thisYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);

for (int i = 1900; i <= thisYear; i++) 
{
    years.add(i);
}

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, years);

//spinner to enter this list to
spinYear = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.yearspin);
```

Here's the XML for the spinner:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/yearspin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What happens when you add `spinYear.setAdapter(adapter)` to your code?

Comment: You're dead right! Thanks!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You're very close.  Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> years = new ArrayList<String>();
int thisYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
for (int i = 1900; i <= thisYear; i++) {
    years.add(Integer.toString(i));
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, years);

Spinner spinYear = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.yearspin);
spinYear.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You just forgot to add

```
spinYear.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: To elaborate, you were missing the conversion from an integer to a string with ```Integer.toString(i);``` and you forgot your call to ```setAdapter()```

Comment: Great that's solved the problem! All I needed to do was to set the adapter! *facepalm*

Comment: @vincentjames501 how can I set the spinner to show the current year and change only if a different year is selected?

Answer (score 6):

I hope it will help you.

```
static final String[] Months = new String[] { "January", "February",
            "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December" };
```

---

```
 // Set years
        ArrayList<String> years = new ArrayList<String>();
        int thisYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        for (int i = 1900; i <= thisYear; i++) {
            years.add(Integer.toString(i));
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, years);

        Spinner spinYear = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerYears);
        spinYear.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Set months
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterMonths = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Months);
        adapterMonths.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        Spinner spinMonths = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerMonths);
        spinMonths.setAdapter(adapterMonths);
        // Set days
        ArrayList<String> days = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
            days.add(Integer.toString(i));
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterDays = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, days);

        Spinner spinDays = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerDays);
        spinDays.setAdapter(adapterDays);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the easy one:

```
ArrayList<String> yearsList = new ArrayList<>();
int current_year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
int count = 60;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    yearsList.add(Integer.toString(current_year - i));
}

ArrayAdapter<String> yearsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), R.layout.dropdown_item, yearsList);
spinYear.setAdapter(yearsAdapter);
```

Just change the value of int count with how many years you want to print prior to the current year.